# How to use ng-repeat with image map area tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create clickable car profile using AngularJS, once I've moved area tag attributes to auto_parts json and bind them with appropriate attributes in ng-repeat then it isn't working. How to fix it?

Please test elements on full page preview.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('imgMapCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.auto_parts = [{
    "shape": "circle",
    "type": "kolo_przod",
    "coords": "193,342,68"
  }, {
    "shape": "circle",
    "type": "kolo_tyl",
    "coords": "743,341,68"
  }, {
    "shape": "poly",
    "type": "okno",
    "coords": "380,220,494,213,512,149,452,157,421,165,369,192,384,199"
  }, {
    "shape": "poly",
    "type": "okno",
    "coords": "536,211,692,202,700,173,664,162,599,152,544,149"
  }, {
    "shape": "poly",
    "type": "drzwi",
    "coords": "301,355,510,354,504,334,510,236,516,213,528,144,462,149,419,162,361,190,300,231,293,253,292,312"
  }, {
    "shape": "poly",
    "type": "drzwi",
    "coords": "510,352,632,349,702,252,712,211,708,202,716,176,657,156,586,145,528,145,516,213,510,235,504,333"
  }]


  $scope.partClicked = function(arg) {
    alert(arg + ' clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="imgMapCtrl">
    <img class="rwdimgmap" src="http://www.mazda.pl/assets/master/cars/all-new-mazda6-sedan/general/12/m6-sedan-red-side.png" alt="auto" width="960" height="540" border="0" usemap="#auto" />
    <map name="auto" id="auto">
      <area ng-repeat="part in auto_parts" shape="part.shape" coords="part.coords" ng-click="partClicked('{{part.type}}')" title="part.type" />
    </map>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is working only HTML snippet:

```
<map name="auto" id="auto">
    <area shape="circle" coords="193,342,68" ng-click="partClicked('kolo_przod')" />
    <area shape="circle" coords="743,341,68" ng-click="partClicked('kolo_tyl')" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="380,220,494,213,512,149,452,157,421,165,369,192,384,199" ng-click="partClicked('okno_przod')" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="536,211,692,202,700,173,664,162,599,152,544,149" ng-click="partClicked('okno_tyl')" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="301,355,510,354,504,334,510,236,516,213,528,144,462,149,419,162,361,190,300,231,293,253,292,312" ng-click="partClicked('drzwi_przod')" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="510,352,632,349,702,252,712,211,708,202,716,176,657,156,586,145,528,145,516,213,510,235,504,333" ng-click="partClicked('drzwi_tyl')" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngRepeat` part has a problem, it should be:

```
<area ng-repeat="part in auto_parts" shape="{{part.shape}}" coords="{{part.coords}}" ng-click="partClicked(part.type)" title="{{part.type}}" />
```

Note, that it's `shape="{{part.shape}}"` with curly braces. Otherwise `part.shape` is interpreted as literally a string and not interpolated. Same with `coords` and `title` attributes.

On the other hand, you don't need interpolation tags in ngClick, as it accepts an expression Angular will understand: `ng-click="partClicked(part.type)"`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5bfNEQxqPfzZxuBJOSWm?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I've tested interpolation only in title="{{part.type}}", but it was invisible :)

Comment: I am using this with ionic but coords become NaN. any idea? Thanks